# Send the same message to list of Actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have a list of actors:

```
listeners: Seq[ActorRef]
```

I want to send the same data to all, now I do:

```
listeners.foreach { l =>
    l ! data
}
```

Is there more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: If we're playing code golf: `listeners.foreach(_ ! data)`. :P

Answer (score 0):

If all your listeners are instances of the same actor type, then you can use a Router Actor with [Broadcast Messages](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/routing.html#Broadcast_Messages)